python: create empty dataclass and populate it on demand
python newbie:  I need to create an empty data model class, populate it with values and then convert it to JSON string, however i am missing something important here.  see error below
my data class:
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ServiceInfo(BaseModel):
    SerialNumber: str
    OS: str
    
class ItemInfo(BaseModel):
    Name: str
    Version: str
    
class AppInfo(BaseModel):
    serviceInfo: ServiceInfo
    itemInfo: ItemInfo

this is how i attempt to use the data model.  i simplified for brevity, but there is a lot of logic here how this data model gets populated:
def myfunction()
    info = AppInfo() # <-- ERROR HERE "2 validation errors for ServiceInfo and ItemInfo"
    info.serviceInfo.SerialNumber = GetSerial()
    info.serviceInfo.OS = "OS 3.19"
    info.itemInfo.Name = GetName()
    info.itemInfo.Version = GetVersion()
    return info.json

thank you in advance

You're doing it the wrong way around. Get the values for properties first, then initialise a new instance of data class with the correct values.
And since AppInfo is the highest level, it should be initiated last, after all other contributing dataclasses have all been initialised:
def myfunction()     
    serial = GetSerial()
    os = "OS 3.19"
    name = GetName()
    version = GetVersion()

    service_info = ServiceInfo(serial, os)
    item_info = ItemInfo(name, version)
    info = AppInfo(service_info, item_info)
    return info.json

